# Adding an integer to the end of a class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the code I'm having trouble with :

```
for (var i; i < 10; i++) {
  if (('.ph' + i).css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
    ('.art' + i).css({'visibility':'visible'});
    break;
  };
};
```

I'm wondering why I can't add the integer to the class name this way, and how I could proceed to get that result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem with your code, just add $ or jQuery (you were trying to access the method `css` of a string):

```
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  if ($('.ph' + i).css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
    $('.art' + i).css({'visibility':'visible'});
    break;
  };
};
```